# Opening app from browser link not working

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have an app with an activity that lets the user purchase some coupons.
In the checkout, the app must open a browser and redirect to a certain URL in order to confirm the checkout, and when it's confirmed, it redirects the browser to a URL that has to open my app -or at least bring it to the foreground.

The problem is that app isn't opening since it doesn't seem to intercept the URL.
My manifest is:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.my.app.HomeActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="ordercompleted"
                android:scheme="x" />
            <data
                android:host="orderrejected"
                android:scheme="y" />
            <data
                android:host="orderfailed"
                android:scheme="z" />
            <data
                android:host="ordercanceled"
                android:scheme="t" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I have breakpoints and everything in the `onCreate` and `onNewIntent` method but still it doesn't capture it; it's just the browser showing "webpage doesn't exist".

Any idea?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: First of all. Are you using default android browser or something else? I have problem with Opera browser but with the System one it works perfect

Comment: @Gooziec I tried both the default and Chrome, and exactly the same.